# Мультимодульный проект

Tags: android, android-studio

Зачем нужны мультимодульные проекты в Android?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что многомодульный проект нужен для того, чтобы можно было запускать модули по отдельности, или у него есть ещё какие-нибудь плюсы?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "запустить на выполнение"? Опишите процесс как вы это себе представляете.

Comment: Запустить процесс сборки приложения - по нажатию на кнопку Run в IDE.

Comment: Создайте конфигурацию и запускайте что угодно. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html

Comment: Не все модули в проекте обязательно должны быть "запускабельными". Конкретно тот проект, что был обозначен в оригинале вопроса, да, для того и создан чтобы вы каждый пример отдельно запускали и все было в одном месте (проекте).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Многомодульный Gradle проект часто используется в случаях:

- библиотека и семпловое приложение для неё.
- несколько библиотек, у которых общая часть ("ядро")

В каждом из случаев можно сделать отдельные проекты, но это добавит сложность в добавлении зависимости к нужной библиотеке. В многомодульном проекте достаточно добавить `implementation project (':lib')`, а в отдельном проекте вам либо придется указывать опубликованную в maven-репозитории либу (snapshot-версию), либо добавлять собранный `aar/jar` (ещё хуже).

Answer (score 2):

Проект по ссылке на GitHub является по сути Gradle-проектом.
Это считается хорошим тоном, распространять Android проекты именно таким образом, без всей этой "мишуры", которую сохраняют IDE.

Соответственно, IDE для сборки и запуска здесь по сути не нужна, достаточно Gradle.

Чтобы корректно открыть такой проект в Android Studio, его нужно сначала импортировать. Android Studio распознает, что это Gradle-проект и создаст всю необходимую ей "мишуру", включая конфигурации для запуска.
Если же что-то у нее не получится, всегда можно что-то добавить и подправить вручную.
Больше информации по ссылке:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html

Изучайте IDE, которой пользуетесь!

Comment: Мой вопрос был немного о другом... Я знаю, как запускать проект из Githab) Вопрос был в том, для чего нужны многомодульные проекты, где они полезны?

Comment: Это он после изменения стал о другом :)

Comment: Да, я поняла, что неправильно задала вопрос и убрала лишнее)